Reproject iris cube from rotated pole to standard lat/lon
I want to remap an iris cube from rotated pole to standard lat/lon coordinates.
I'm used to using rioaxarray, where converting to unrotated (or any coordinate) is extremely simple, for example:
import xarray as xr
import rioxarray as rxr
orig_proj = xr.open_rasterio(fname)
standard_proj = orig_proj.rio.reproject('epsg:4326')

But I can't seem to find the same functionality in iris (or ants).
Some dead ends... I know there is:
lons, lats = iris.analysis.cartography.unrotate_pole(rot_lons, rot_lats, pole_lon, pole_lat)

However the resulting lat/lons miss the full extent of the unrotated cube... results are only a subset of the full domain in standard coordinates.
I also know there is:
cb = iris.load_cube(frame)
cb_standard = cb.regrid(cb_on_standard_grid, iris.analysis.Nearest())

But this relies on a cube of predetermined projection and resolution, which I don't have. I simply want to retroject my existing rotated cube onto standard lat/lon coordinates.

from iris.analysis.cartography import project; import cartopy.crs as ccrs; cb_standard = project(cb, ccrs.PlateCarree())[0] ?
